# Update Matrix Haskell

Tags: haskell, matrix, functional-programming

I will represent matrices in a project by a list of lists [[a]]

- Is this a good idea or should I better use Arrays?
- How do I change the element on place with index (i,j)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course, list-based solutions are never as fast as optimised tight arrays because of the necessary indirections, with all its cache-locality problems. However, that's only a constant overhead factor (possibly quite big though, something in the order of 100).

However, interestingly, the nested-list approach to matrices is not quite as bad as it may seem: lists remain the data structure that's most naturally dealt with in a traditional purely-functional manner. As said by millimoose, you cannot just change an element in-place in a pure way, you have to make a copy of the whole thing with one element changed*. For *n* ✕ *n* tight-array matrices, this is *O* (*n*<sup>2</sup>) – hardly acceptable for larger *n*.

While random access in a list of length *m* is already *O* (*m*) and thus much worse than for arrays, **it doesn't get any worse for more complex operations**. You can "modify" a list in *O* (*m*), you can access an *n* ✕ *n* nested list in *O* (*n*), and you can modify it in *O* (*n*)! So if you want to do nondestructive updates on large matrices, `[[a]]` is actually faster than `Array a i`.

Oh, how this works – well, something like

```
type Matrix a = [[a]]
updateMatrixAt :: (Int,Int) -> (a->a) -> Matrix a -> Matrix a
updateMatrixAt(i,j) f mat
 | (upperRows, thisRow : lowerRows ) <- splitAt i mat
 , (leftCells, thisCell: rightCells) <- splitAt j thisRow
         =                  upperRows
          ++ (leftCells ++ (f thisCell): rightCells)
                          : lowerRows
 | otherwise = error "Tried to index matrix outside range"
```

will do the trick.

---

*There [have been attempts to avoid this](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Arrays#DiffArray_.28module_Data.Array.Diff.29), but I'm afraid this has proven a dead end. If you want really high performance, you should use destructive updates in the `ST` monad, there's nothing wrong with it though it may not be quite as nice.

Comment: +1 Another excellent and well thought out answer from @leftatroundabout.

Answer (score 5):

How about using your own data type wrapping a `Map (Int,Int) a`? Changing an element is trivial, and especially for sparse matrices you save a lot of memory.

Comment: +1 Definitely worth a thought for sparse matrices. For dense ones, it needs quite a lot _more_ memory. The handling is rather different from ordinary matrix types, but not necessarily worse.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I change the element on place with index (i,j)?

Generally speaking, you can't. You have to create a new matrix with the one element changed. (Using `Array` instead of a list would make this slightly easier with [the `//` operator](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/haskell98-2.0.0.2/Array.html#v%3a-47--47-).)  It seems like you could use [`MArray`](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Arrays#Mutable_IO_arrays_.28module_Data.Array.IO.29) to do in-place changes, but then pretty much all your code would have to use `IO`.

Comment: You don't want to use `MArray` (unless you're in `IO` anyway), there's `STArray`.